# It's possible run commands without Dockerfile inside docker-compose.yml using RUN command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have **php** service in my `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Can I remove `Dockerfile` and install php extensions inside `docker-compose.yml` instead?

Comment: It'd be better practice to `COPY` the application in the Dockerfile and remove almost all of the `docker-compose.yml` settings.  Is there a specific reason you want to remove the image build step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can try below to install the extension first and then start `php-fpm`

```
php:
  image: php:7.4-fpm-alpine
  command: sh -c "docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql && php-fpm"
```

Comment: This command in each building wiil be runned? I mean what php extension will be installed on each building again? @Adiii

Comment: This will be repeated _every single time_ you run the container; it will take time and network bandwidth.  If you have it in a Dockerfile it will only get run when you rebuild the image, and then the downloaded extension can be reused.

Comment: So, you recommend use separate Dockerfile to install extensions? @DavidMaze

Comment: If I was asked to work on a project that had this `docker-compose.yml` file, after looking at `git log` to understand how it got this way, I'd probably convert it to look like the question.

Comment: Yes exactly agree with @david, but as you ask for the sake requirement so posted answers accordingly otherwise you are doing fine in the Dockerfile Mentioned in question